# How to format number string in php like this

Tags: php

I want to customize my $number variable so that it will return like this 00:00:00

I want to insert **":"** after every 2 numbers

Example:

```
$num = 120834;
```

So i want the output like this : `12:08:34`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php with implode seems like what you want. Something like `$result = implode(":", str_split(strval($num), 2));`. Although there's no check for digits count.

Comment: Stepping back, you might think about whether your code should be managing those values as `Date` objects to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `implode()` and `str_split()` jointly to the job:

```
$new = implode(":", str_split(strval($num), 2));
```

Alternatively, If you have always 8 digits, just try this:

```
$num = '120466';
$new = substr($num, 0, 2) .':'. substr($num, 2, 2).':'. substr($num, 4, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most readable way:

You can use [str_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-split.php) to separate it in an array based on the number of digits you want, 2 in this case.

```
$num = 120834;
$numParts = str_split($num, 2);

// then you can simply add it to a string
echo "$numParts[0]:$numParts[1]:$numParts[2]"; //12:08:34
```

Heres a function to do it easily for you:

```
//Then you can simply pass in the number you want to convert
function numberToTime($num)
{

    $numParts = str_split($num, 2);

    return "$numParts[0]:$numParts[1]:$numParts[2]";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [chunk_split](https://www.php.net/manual/function.chunk-split.php) for this:

substr(chunk_split("120834", 2, ":"), 0, -1)